# Visual Studio build emoji continously displays

Tags: visual-studio

The following icon/emoji never goes away. It continuously displays regardless of if I am building or not. How can I repair the problem?

[image]

Comment: That looks like the "building project(s)" icon. Do you have a build going on in the background?

Comment: it is as I suspected the build icon. It never stopped 'moving' even when nothing was being built. Based on your comment I re-built the solution in both Release and then Debug. It has finally gone away. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm the issue. For me, this icon is also there most of the time, whether it's building or not. Even during debugging, it sometimes is there.

Comment: @PMF If you do a rebuild does that fix the problem?

Comment: @Peter No, it does not. The symbol stays there, regardless of what I do. It even stays there during debugging.

Comment: Then I really don't know what fixed it for me. The only other thing I did what tootle around in Configuration Manager for awhile.

Comment: The problem came back and will not go away.

Comment: The problem persists

Comment: The problem persists some more

Answer (score 0):

That icon means it is building something. Checkout the output window (ctrl+alt+o) and select "Build" from the drop-down at the top to see what is happening.